# RavenDb MapReduce over subset of Data

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

Say I have the given document structure in RavenDb

```
public class Car {
    public string Manufacturer {get;set;}
    public int BuildYear {get;set;}
    public string Colour {get;set;}
    public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

When the user searches for all cars of colour Red and build year 2010, I want to show them a grouping for manufacturer as such:

Toyota (12) 
 
Mazda  (30)

Given there are 12 toyotas and 30 mazdas that are red in colour and build year 2010.

This is a simplified use case. The user can really specify tons of criteria for the cars they want to match. Once I have a list of cars matching that criteria then I need to group that result set on every feature and show a count. 
Its like a MapReduce but on a subset of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afif, what you mean is called a *faceted search*. Thanks to the underlying Lucene.NET component RavenDB is very good at that. Take a look here: http://ravendb.net/documentation/faceted-search

Comment: Can't thank you enough Daniel for your prompt response. I walked straight into that feature. :)

Comment: From that Camera example, say when a user searches for a criteria, for e.g. all cameras under $200, we want to display a grouping by megapixels and Model combined as the key. How would the Facets look in such a scenario?

Comment: I wrote (some) of the faceted search code, so hopefully I can help. At the moment you can't do combined grouping like that. It would be a nice feature to have but I'll have to have a think about whether it could actually be implemented.