# Retrieve all facets for RavenDB query when facets for a given key are over 1024

Tags: limit, ravendb, facet

When I apply the 'ToFacets("facets/CameraFacets")' extension on the 'IQueryable' that comes from my query, I find the count on one of the 'IEnumerable' collections against a facet in the dictionary is 1024. I know for sure there are more, but how do I retrieve them? Will increasing the safe limit automatically give me all values, also is there another way of doing this without having to increase that limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you change the safe limit it will pull in more facets, take a look at the `HandleTermsFacet(..)` [in the code](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Queries/FacetedQueryRunner.cs).

**However**, I wouldn't recommend it. It's a perf issue because 1024 facets means you are doing 1024 seperate queries.

If you need to deal with this many facets, you are better off using a [Map/Reduce index](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-indexes-map-reduce), also see [this blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4435/map-reduce-a-visual-explanation)

Comment: Matt, how would one do mapreduce over data that is determined by predicates at runtime? I ask [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843739/ravendb-mapreduce-over-subset-of-data) question to start with and was told facets is what I need.

Comment: when you say 1024 facets mean 1024 queries, does it mean say if the database has a 1000 models of different cars, and I want to show a count against each after applying some user criteria, then essentially I am running the query for each model in the database to get a count? is this how one would have to do it if using map reduce and not the ToFacets extension?

Comment: Yes, facets are mainly when you have very small (a dozen or so) items that you want to look at, not when you have hundreds or thousands. It isn't possible to answer your question with the given information, please post the model and what you are trying to do on the mailing list.